# jquery mobile - simple page transition snaps

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

While learning jquery mobile I set up a basic page transition that would slide me from page1 to page2.  Regardless of the library versions I use, I get the same error (via console - page just hangs) within the swipeleft/swiperight/click event that I try to implement -

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MenuButtonRounded is not defined 
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: scaleImage is not defined

Any suggestions as to why this would happen ? sample code below -

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
           <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
          <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
           </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
           <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
               <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>

           </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page --> 


<script>
    $("#page1").on("swiperight",function(event){
        $.mobile.changePage( "page2");      // this is where my error occurs!

        });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working on my end, however it's saying page2 (404 error) doesn't exist.

Check out the jQuery docs on Swipe To Navigate

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/swipe-page/

Comment: In the end I grabbed another boilerplate and it resolved the issue, whatever it was! Thanks for your feedback though.